# String.Replace using Settings not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, replace, settings

I have a string.replace method as follows:

```
SomeString.Replace("stringvar", Settings.Default.stringvarsetting);
```

The substring "stringvar" of `SomeString` is not changed to the default value of the setting `stringvarsetting`. However "stringvar" can be found in `SomeString`, as `SomeString.Contains("stringvar")` returns 'true'.

Is there an alternate method to replace that I am supposed to be using in this situation? If not, how else can I solve my problem?

Comment: Just in case... Method `Replace` returns a string that is the actual result of the operation. Is that it?

Comment: The result of replace method is a new string

Comment: DOH! So obvious, thanks everyone for the rapid responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the effect you require, you need to do:

```
SomeString = SomeString.Replace("stringvar", Settings.Default.stringvarsetting);
```

Thus, string.Replace does not replace the value of the variable. You have to specify that.

Comment: DOH! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code, basically you are not preserving the resultant string:

```
SomeString = SomeString.Replace("stringvar", Settings.Default.stringvarsetting);
```

Comment: I feel silly! Thanks for your help but I will accept MIhai's answer as he was first.